# HBASE distributed mode on HADOOP stuck

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-zookeeper

I am trying to configure HBASE Distributed mode on 3 node hadoop cluster.

problem is when i start start-all-sh ,

my cursor stucks after writing

```
hadoop@namenode1:/usr/local/hbase/bin$ start-hbase.sh
hadoop@namenode1's password: datanode2: starting zookeeper, logging to /usr/local/hbase/bin/../logs/hbase-hadoop-zookeeper-datanode2.out
datanode1: starting zookeeper, logging to /usr/local/hbase/bin/../logs/hbase-hadoop-zookeeper-datanode1.out
```

and it is not proceeding further . It is kind of stuck .

my hbase.site.xml

```
`<configuration>

  <property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>hdfs://namenode1:10001/hbase</value>
  </property>

   <property>
    <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir</name>
    <value>hdfs://namenode1:10001/zookeeper</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
    <value>namenode1,datanode1,datanode2</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort</name>
    <value>2181</value>
  </property>

</configuration>
`
```

however i did not install zookeeper separatly

my data nodes show

```
4387 Jps
3978 DataNode
4332 HQuorumPeer
4126 NodeManager
```

name node only show

```
`hadoop@namenode1:/usr/local/hbase/conf$ jps
4832 ResourceManager
4676 SecondaryNameNode
4443 NameNode
5437 Jps`
```

Please help in resolving issue . I am stuck.

now when i press enter on cursor

```
hadoop@namenode1:/usr/local/hbase/bin$ start-hbase.sh
hadoop@namenode1's password: datanode2: starting zookeeper, logging to /usr/local/hbase/bin/../logs/hbase-hadoop-zookeeper-datanode2.out
datanode1: starting zookeeper, logging to /usr/local/hbase/bin/../logs/hbase-hadoop-zookeeper-datanode1.out

namenode1: Connection closed by UNKNOWN
starting master, logging to /usr/local/hbase/logs/hbase-hadoop-master-namenode1.out
hadoop@namenode1's password: datanode2: starting regionserver, logging to /usr/local/hbase/bin/../logs/hbase-hadoop-regionserver-datanode2.out
datanode1: starting regionserver, logging to /usr/local/hbase/bin/../logs/hbase-hadoop-regionserver-datanode1.out

hadoop@namenode1's password: namenode1: Permission denied, please try again.

hadoop@namenode1's password: namenode1: Permission denied, please try again.

namenode1: Permission denied (publickey,password).
```

and then namenode shows

```
hadoop@namenode1:/usr/local/hbase/bin$ jps
4832 ResourceManager
4676 SecondaryNameNode
5559 HMaster
5751 Jps
4443 NameNode
```

and datanode1 show

```
hadoop@datanode1:/usr/local/hbase/conf$ jps
4610 Jps
4502 HRegionServer
3978 DataNode
4332 HQuorumPeer
4126 NodeManager
```

and datanode2 show

```
hadoop@datanode2:~$ jps
2465 DataNode
2601 NodeManager
2922 HRegionServer
2794 HQuorumPeer
3054 Jps
```

Comment: Did you configure a passwordless ssh?

Comment: yes i have added passwordless ssh between all nodes , but it is failing when  trying to login same machine.

Comment: thanks @Abhinav . I got a hint from ur reply

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually first of all i needed to install zookeeper in distributed mode and also

for password less ssh i did not configure self ssh passwordless

so ran

```
sudo cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Thanks @Abhinav guys